# Disable checkboxes after a certain number are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title explains, My code should disable a checkbox when the user selects a certain number.

The code works and does disable a checkbox.

But the problem is the text that changes isn't disabled. Here's my code:

```
let $compare = $(".visible");
        $compare.on("click", (event) => {
             if ($('input:checked').length < 3) {
                $(event.currentTarget).text($(event.currentTarget).text() === "Item added" ? "Compare" : "Item added");

                $(event.currentTarget).addClass("visible");

                     $("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("disabled");

            }
            else {
                  $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled", "disabled");
                $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").removeAttr("disabled");
                event.currentTarget.checked = false;
            }
        })
```

No errors and the code works to the point it disables a checkbox. But the text still changes even if the checkbox is disabled.

```
heres the function that displays the data into html:




 const displayOutputHome = (games, hasCheckbox) => {

        let output = "";
        var x = 0;
        games.forEach(game => {

            if (game.Type === "Coming Soon") {

                x++;

                let ratingDiv = $("<div class='rating'></div>");

                for (var i = 0; i < game.Rating; i++) {
                    ratingDiv.append('<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>');
                }
                for (var i = game.Rating; i < 5; i++) {
                    ratingDiv.append('<span class="fa fa-star"></span>');
                }

                output += `

                    <li>
    <div class=""><input name="gameSelected" id="togg` + x + `" type="checkbox"><label for="togg` + x + `" class="${hasCheckbox ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}">Compare</label></div></li>
    <li><a class="newGame" href=${game.link}?id=${game.ID}><img class="frontGames" src="${game.image}" alt="gameImage">
              <p><b>Name:</b>${game.Name}<br>
                <b>Release Date:</b>${game.ReleaseDate}</br>
                <b>Genres:</b>${game.Genres}</br>
                <b>Retail Price:</b>${game.RetailPrice}</br>

        </li>`;

            }
        })
        return output;

    }
```

Comment: Please add your HTML and indent your JS code

Comment: Could work with $(this).attr('checked', false);$(this).text('item added');

Comment: @GalAbra the code is coming from an ajax file and being displayed with javascript. i can still put some of it if you wish?

Comment: @RichardMarks put your rendered html in the question...

Comment: use "change" instead of "click" listener. A disabled checkbox is clickable.

Comment: where exactly @AliSheikhpour? how will that make a difference? the text will still change regardlessv

Comment: The disconnect is that your click event is on the label, not the input (checkbox) and when you target the checkbox in the code, its not contextual to the label that was clicked.  your grabbing all the checkboxes with your selector `"input[type=checkbox]"` -- you need to use the `find` function in jquery to find the relevant checkbox that is related to the label that was clicked...  I will see if I can submit another answer that fixes your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would change your `click` function.  I separated the code managing the state of the checkbox and label associated with the click event, from the code that enables / disables the available options.

Here is the code:

```
$compare.on("click", (event) => {
    // get chkbox id from 'for' attr on label
    var chkboxID = $(event.currentTarget).prop("for"); 

    // toggle label, toggle checkbox
    if ($(event.currentTarget).text() === "Item added") {
        $(event.currentTarget).text("Compare");
        $("#" + chkboxID).removeAttr("checked");
    } else {
        $(event.currentTarget).text("Item added");
        $("#" + chkboxID).prop("checked","checked");
    }

    // enable / disable checks
    if ($('input:checked').length < 3) {
        $(event.currentTarget).addClass("visible");
        $("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: Did this help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to get the job done, but with a slightly different approach.

Once you've reached the number checked that is desired, then you disable the rest and only allow 'unchecking' items.

Then if one is unchecked and you are below the threshold, then all of the items are re-enabled and are available for checking.

Hope this helps! Code below -

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="check1"  /> Check 1 
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="check2"  /> Check 2 
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="check3"  /> Check 3 
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check4" value="check4"  /> Check 4 
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check5" value="check5"  /> Check 5 
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check6" value="check6"  /> Check 6
</div>
```

JavaScript / jQuery:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
    var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if (count < 3) {  // we only want to allow 3 to be checked here.
        $("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("disabled");
        // re-enable all checkboxes
    } else {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled","disabled");
        // disable all checkboxes
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").removeAttr("disabled");
        // only enable the elements that are already checked.
    }
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gfdata/0sh4p2ce/7/

I've updated my JS Fiddle to work with a dataset that constantly changes.  I will check out your edits...

new Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gfdata/0sh4p2ce/27/

Comment: thanks for that, but with my function the text changes when you click the checkbox, what can i do about that in this situation looking at your code

Comment: My `on("click", function() { /**/ });` replaces your click function in your script.  as long as you call that function to assign the "Click" event handler after you  redraw the HTML -- you should be all set.  CAVEAT: my CSS selector may not be accurate for your html.  make sure you're using the right CSS selector for your code

Comment: and should the box remain checked if the text changes?

Comment: actually I've got an idea. hold pls.

Comment: ive updated my answer with a better working one, tho its still buggy because of the 3rd item, so ill wait on your input :D